# Notation for the set $\{0,1\}$

Tags: notation, bit-strings

When doing some complexity theory, I get bored of typing all the time the set $\{0,1\}$. Is there some widely used alternate fancy notation?

Comment: Some authors use $\mathbb{B}$ (as in Boolean).

Comment: I see sometimes the notation $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, that is, the set with the first positive $n$ elements. I dont know if it can be useful for your case.

Comment: I second the $[n]$ notation; I've usually seen it in combinatorics when it is useful to talk about $n$-element sets. Also, for the people saying $\Bbb F_2$ or $\Bbb Z_2$, I'm not sure this is the best choice unless you are actually going to be using the group/field operations.

Comment: @ElliotG the question was about existence of a notation. Whether it is Best choice is subjective. Its a bit strong to downvote a bona fide notation.

Comment: Of course. That wasn't my down vote by the way.

Comment: But if the main issue is your typing it every time... what about `\newcommand{\bool}{\{0,1\}}`? (Note that also allows you to switch notation very easily after the fact)

Comment: @ClementC.it was more a matter of being bored of the notation per sé, but your comment is noted and appreciated!

Comment: @ElliotG sorry wasn't intending to implicate you.

Answer (score 4):

How about using $2$ or maybe $\mathbf{2}$ if you also use the number $2$ in other contexts and want to avoid confusion? In fact, under a standard construction of the natural numbers in set theory we indeed have the equality $2 = \{ 0, 1 \}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)) and this notation is quite common in set theory and topology.

Comment: Drawback: this is going to confuse the hell out of everyone doing complexity theory, as the most uncommon notation there. (One does not write papers for oneself.)

Comment: @ClementC. I don't claim to know the conventions of complexity theory articles. If all articles use $\{ 0, 1 \}$, then obviously one should just use that. I just suggested an alternative notation which is common in other areas of mathematics. However, I'm a bit surprised the notation $\mathbf{2}^A$ is not used to denote boolean functions on $A$ and if it is used, then obviously one should be comfortable with using $\mathbf{2}$ to denote $\{ 0, 1 \}$.

Comment: Well, I for one have never seen it. Also, my comment is mostly for the OP: looking for "alternate fancy notation[s]" because (s)he is "bored" with the widely used ones may not be a good idea if the goal is to effectively communicate ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen $\mathbb Z_2$ used to denote that set, with obvious extension to $\mathbb Z_n $

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2$ is usually a ring on the set $\{0,1\}$ though, not just the set itself, so this might not be the best choice.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Agreed. If you use the name commonly associated with the ring, you imply that you use something about the ring structure, but it looks like OP is only referring to the set.

Comment: @alexisolson How is 'usually' quantified? It can just as easily be stated, and supported by evidence/links, its associated with the set. The point is it is associated with multiple things and they are all valid associatons.

Comment: 'Usually' is difficult to quantify. Personally, I've 'rarely' seen $\mathbb Z_2$ used without its algebraic baggage. It's a good suggestion, but one should be aware of the extra connotations it 'frequently' carries.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another notation. If you have used [Finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) then [GF(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)) or just $\text{F}_2$ must suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This is denoted by $\mathbb{F}_2$, the simplest field. Note that in advanced math, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ uses for dyadic integers which is an uncountable set.

Comment: Yes and no. The underlying set is right (at least one realization of it), but a field more than a set. I understand the intent, though.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** there may be, *but you should not.*

If you are doing research in complexity theory, your goal is not only to derive new results and ideas, but also, crucially, *to communicate them to others.* In particular, talking a language the other researchers in that field are familiar with is paramount: nobody wants to decipher a paper where the author chooses, for no apparent purpose, different notations for every single notion. So if your rationale is that

> [you] get bored of typing all the time the set $\{0,1\}$.

and are looking for

> alternate **fancy** notation

(emphasis mine), then the answer is: **don't do it.** Using a "widely used" notation from a different field may sound cool, but if the complexity theorists don't know it, then it's a bad idea. And if you have to *ask* for alternate notations, it means you haven't seen them in the papers of complexity theory that (I assume) you have read, so... they are not, by definition widely used in complexity theory.

Now, don't get me wrong:

- people in (algebraic) property testing and some subfields complexity theory often use $\mathbb{F}_2$; but it's *because* they want to use the algebraic structure of $\mathbb{F}_2$, and often consider $\mathbb{F}_p$ as well;
- people in Boolean Fourier analysis will often switch to $\{-1,+1\}$ (actually, $\{+1,-1\}$), but *because* it is convenient (to be able to write the characters $\chi_S$ in a multiplicative way, which often simplifies the proofs and derivations).

In both cases/examples above, people do this **for a reason,** and it's widely recognized in these respective areas of (or intersections of these areas with) complexity theory. Boredom is not such a reason.

Comment: While I agree with the spirit of this answer, I ask for some charity of interpretation of the question. My concern here is that we may have gotten stuck with bad notation when there is a clearly better notation lying somewhere else. Playfully exploring the design space of papers when your goal is to communicate seems worth a shot IMO. I respect your opinion though, and let us agree that innovation for the sake of innovation is harmful for paper writing.